# Find the longest region length in a bed file using awk and/or bash

Tags: bash, awk

I need to find the longest region in a whole bed file. I know how to find the coverage of a certain chr but I do not know how to find the coverage for each individual region (aka the length end-start, or $3-$2). Once I know the command for that I know how to sort by number. I only know intro bash and intro awk. Any help would be great!

Comment: Your question doesn't make any sense at all. What is a bed-file? Please update question with some input data and the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

A shot in the dark based on: http://uswest.ensembl.org/info/website/upload/bed.html?redirect=no

Using the data there:

```
chr1  213941196  213942363
chr1  213942363  213943530
chr1  213943530  213944697
chr2  158364697  158365864
chr2  158365864  158367031
chr3  127477031  127478198
chr3  127478198  127479365
chr3  127479365  127480532
chr3  127480532  127481699
```

and noting that the only place I see region mentioned there is related to the chromosome name, I'll assume a region represents multiple lines with the same `$1` field.

Summing over regions can be done like this then:

```
awk '{ a[$1]+=($3-$2) } END {for( k in a ) { print k, a[k] }}' data
```

which gives output like:

```
chr1 3501
chr2 2334
chr3 4668
```

which you could then pipe to sort using "-nr -k2,2" flags like:

```
awk '{ a[$1]+=($3-$2) } END { for( k in a ) { print k, a[k] } }' data | sort -nr -k2,2
chr3 4668
chr1 3501
chr2 2334
```

The awk is:

- Creating an associative array `a` and populating the `$1` keys with differences of `$3-$2`.
- Each time the same region is encountered, update the associated sum ( the `+=` )
- In the `END` block, loop through the array and output the key/value pairs.
- Optionally, send the output to sort with flags to reverse, numeric sort over the second field in the output.